# Finding positions of multiple elements in lists

Tags: list-manipulation

I realise that

```
Position[{2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64}, 4]
```

will return

```
{{2}}
```

I would like to do something like this:

```
Position[{2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64}, {4, 32, 64}]
```

and get

```
{{2}, {5}, {6}}
```

I have searched, but can't ind anything - I am clearly missing something obvious :/

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`Position` takes a pattern as last argument. Therefore, the most direct way is

```
Position[{2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64}, 4 | 32 | 64]
```

or

```
Position[{2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64}, Alternatives @@ {4, 32, 64}]
```

if you have your numbers in a list.

Comment: Great - the latter is more useful for me - very simple question, I know - but hugely time saving! Many thanks :)

Answer (score 5):

If you want them in the order listed there is the direct approach.

```
 Flatten[Position[{2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64}, #], 1] & /@ {32, 64,4}

     ->     { {5}, {6}, {2} }
```